# setting ngif on dynamic data

Tags: html, angular, typescript

this is my html file -

```
 <div class="container">
            <div class="container__usernamesContainer">
                <a 
                class="container__usernamesContainer--text" 
                [routerLink]="'/user/' + user.getId()"
                *ngFor="let user of getUsers()">
                    Username: {{ user.getUsername() }}
                </a>
            </div>
        <div class="container__statusesContainer">
            <span class="container__statusesContainer--text" *ngFor="let user of getUsers()">
                    Status: {{ user.getStatusLabel() }}
            </span> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

i want to make the `Username: {{ user.getUsername() }}` clickable by an 'a' tag only when the `{{ user.getStatusLabel()` is Success, how can i achive that with ngif?

i assume i need to compare the username to the status and then put the condition if success then make it clickable with an 'a' tag.

i dont know how to write if correctly, would love some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

Use `anchor` tag only when the condition is satisfied. Or else use a `span`

```
<div *ngFor="let user of getUsers()">
    <a 
        class="container__usernamesContainer--text" 
        [routerLink]="'/user/' + user.getId()"
        *ngIf="user.getStatusLabel() === 'Success'"
        >
            Username: {{ user.getUsername() }}
    </a>
    <span 
        class="container__usernamesContainer--text"
        *ngIf="user.getStatusLabel() !== 'Success'"
        >
            Username: {{ user.getUsername() }}
    </span>
</div>
```

**Option 2**
Make the `routerLink` property conditional.

```
<a 
    class="container__usernamesContainer--text" 
    *ngFor="let user of getUsers()"
    [routerLink]="user.getStatusLabel() === 'Success'? '/user/' + user.getId(): ''"
    >
        Username: {{ user.getUsername() }}
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add two elements to display according to the condition

```
<div class="container__usernamesContainer">
    <ng-container  *ngFor="let user of getUsers()">
        <a *ngIf="user.getStatusLabel()" class="container__usernamesContainer--text" [routerLink]="'/user/' + user.getId()">
            Username: {{ user.getUsername() }}
        </a>
        <a *ngIf="!user.getStatusLabel()" class="container__usernamesContainer--text">
            Username: {{ user.getUsername() }}
        </a>
    </ng-container>
</div>
<div class="container__statusesContainer">
    <span class="container__statusesContainer--text" *ngFor="let user of getUsers()">
        Status: {{ user.getStatusLabel() }}
    </span>
</div>
```